# Joining separate log to main Rails development log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, development-environment, delayed-job

This is the reverse of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337739/how-to-log-something-in-rails-in-an-independent-log-file) I have seen [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474970/how-can-i-log-rails-errors-into-a-separate-log-file) elsewhere, in which someone wants to see how to create an another, separate Rails log from the main development log. For some reason, my Rails app is logging my DelayedJob gem's activity to a separate log (`delayed_job.log`), but I want it to log to the main `development.log` file. I am using the Workless gem and NewRelic as well, should this be potentially relevant (although I experimented on this by removing NewRelic, and the issue still remained).

I'm not clear on how this happened. However, I was having some trouble earlier with seeing SQL insertions and deletions in my log, and another user kindly [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569546/rails-sql-insert-statements-not-showing-up-in-console) that I use the following in an initializer file:

```
if defined?(Rails) && !Rails.env.nil?
  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = logger
  ActiveResource::Base.logger = logger
end
```

Once I did this, I saw the SQL statements, but no longer saw the DelayedJob information in the main development log.

So my question is: How can I make sure that DelayedJob activity logs to the main development log? I don't mind if it also logs to a separate log, but the important thing is that I see its activity in my Mac's console.

Please let me know if you'd like more code from my app - I'd be happy to provide it. Much thanks from a Rails newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. All thanks to Seamus Abshere's answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500200/getting-delayed-job-to-log). I put what he posted below in an initializer file. This got delayed_job to log to my development.rb file (huzzah!).

However, delayed_job still isn't logging into my console (for reasons I still don't understand). I solved that by opening a new console tab and entering `tail -f log/development.log`.

Different from what Seamus wrote, though, `auto-flushing=true` is deprecated in Rails 4 and my Heroku app crashed. I resolved this by removing it from my initializer file and placing it in my `environments/development.rb` file as `config.autoflush_log = true`. However, I found that neither of the two types of flushing were necessary to make this work.

Here is his code (without the auto-flushing):

```
file_handle = File.open("log/#{Rails.env}_delayed_jobs.log", (File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT))
# Be paranoid about syncing
file_handle.sync = true
# Hack the existing Rails.logger object to use our new file handle
Rails.logger.instance_variable_set :@log, file_handle
# Calls to Rails.logger go to the same object as Delayed::Worker.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
```

If the above code doesn't work, try replacing `Rails.logger` with `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: I already tried to add `Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` but it did not work